# Boost - unordered_set tutorial/examples/ANYTHING?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++11, unordered-set

I'd like to use `unordered_set` in a project.

However, documentation for it is either incomplete or just a technical reference, no examples.

Can anyone provide links to online resources which deal with it? Books also welcome, preferably free. Google searching returned nothing of value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's little docs on it because it behaves exactly like [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), with the exception that it requires a hashing and equals function instead of a comparison function. Just look up examples for `std::set`, and replace them with [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) and you should be fine.

If you need to write a hashing function, there are examples in the docs, i.e. [this one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/unordered/hash_equality.html).

Comment: It may have an interface very similar to std::set, but its behavior is different.  Aside from the ways in which hashing makes it faster, there are also ways in which Boost's `unordered_set` can be slower, such as: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3693

Comment: @John: It's performance characteristics are different, and it cannot be iterated in an ordered manner (well, it is called `unordered_set`). Otherwise it behaves exactly as `std::set` does.

Comment: The erase performance issue has since been fixed: 
Quote from boost 1.61_0:
Notes:
In older versions this could be inefficient because it had to search through several buckets to find the position of the returned iterator. The data structure has been changed so that this is no longer the case, and the alternative erase methods have been deprecated.

Answer (score 10):

**Code for the most common use case:**

```
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
using boost::unordered_set;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main (void)
{   
    // Initialize set
    unordered_set<string> s;
    s.insert("red");
    s.insert("green");
    s.insert("blue");

    // Search for membership
    if(s.find("red") != s.end())
        cout << "found red" << endl;
    if(s.find("purple") != s.end())
        cout << "found purple" << endl;
    if(s.find("blue") != s.end())
        cout << "found blue" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
found red
found blue
```

**More Information**

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/find/

Answer (score 4):

The boost containers are effectively an implementation of the interface first specified by the C++ Standard Library Technical Report (known as TR1), as mentioned in the boost docs. They seem to be part of the new standards working draft by now. Google turns up some more documentation/examples if you search for tr1 and unordered_set. I like the MSDN reference, which also has some samples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982739.aspx

http://www.google.de/search?q=tr1+unordered_set

Answer (score 2):

I would try using the same methods of access that you use on `std::set` or other containers, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/unordered.html seems to agree.